# How could I remove/delete the rules from "FTP Authorization Rules" in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, iis, ftp, iis-7, authorization

I am trying to use Powershell to delete the "FTP Authorization Rules" from IIS7.

Thought I found the "add-webconfiguration" Cmdlet and can add a new rule in "FTP Authorization Rules" successfully, but can't find any way to delete the rules.

In the get-help add-webconfiguration, there is a reference to remove-webconfiguration, but this cmdlet does not exist.
If I try "get-help Remove-WebConfiguration", system will show 4 item as following but NO "Remove-WebConfiguration":

Remove-WebConfigurationBackup

Remove-WebConfigurationLocation

Remove-WebConfigurationLock

Remove-WebConfigurationProperty

Dose anyone know how to remove the specified rule in "FTP Authorization Rules"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "Remove-WebConfigurationProperty" can success to delete the rules

---

Remove-WebConfigurationProperty  -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -location 'FTP' -filter "system.ftpServer/security/authorization" -name "." -AtElement @{users='';roles='dyk';permissions='1'}